# Is it possible to use @EJB annotation to inject EJBs through different servers?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I have 2 session beans, OrderBean and InventoryBean which are deployed at different weblogic servers.

The OrderBean needs to access the InventoryBean to check if the supply is sufficient.

Currently, I use JNDI look up to locate the InventoryBean and it works fine.

Now I'm wondering if it is possible to use @EJB to inject InventoryBean by providing the JNDI name and the URL in xml or somewhere else.

Answer (score 8):

Finally I found a way to do this.

i. Configure the foreign JNDI on the weblogic server and link the remote EJB to a local JNDI name.

For example:

```
Local JNDI:
InventoryBean#com.pkg.InventoryBean (MAPPEDNAME#FULLNAME)
link to
Remote JNDI:
ServiceBean#com.pkg.InventoryBean
```

ii. Configure ejb-ref in ejb-jar.xml

```
ejb-ref-name -> ejb/InventoryBean
remote -> com.pkg.InventoryService
mapped-name -> InventoryBean
```

iii. Add the @EJB annotation in OrderBean

```
@EJB(name = "ejb/InventoryBean")
private InventoryService inventoryService;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is not possible through EJB annotations, but you can configure [foreign JNDI](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/jndi/ManageForeignJNDI.html)  on your WebLogic server and refer to your remote EJB as a local JNDI name. Though, I never tried that, but I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks, actually I have tried that before and it works fine just like you said.

Comment: But is it possibile by an annotation, or I have to lookup local jndi by coding it?

Answer (score 0):

It is very AS-specific.

JBoss 7+ makes it possible if you:

1. Define `outbound-socket-binding`, `security-realm` and `remote-outbound-connection` in the standalone file (all referring to the remote JBoss instance).
2. Add a `jboss-ejb-client.xml` to the META-INF folder of your packaged application, with a `remoting-ejb-receiver` for every connection needed by the application.
3. Inject the remote EJB with`@EJB(lookup = "<jndi_name>")`

Let me know if further details are needed.

Give a look at:

- [JBoss configuration for remote connections](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance)
- [An article about Glassfish-Glassfish remote connections](https://blogs.oracle.com/chengfang/entry/glassfish_to_glassfish_remote_ejb)