# Injecting a Remote EJB through @EJB annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

Simple question: when I deploy an EJB on a given Application Server, and then I want to consume it from an EJB deployed on diferent Application Server (remotely, of course), how can I inject a remote instance of the former EJB inside the second one?

It should be something like this:

```
 @Stateless
 public class EJBClient {

   @EJB("myRemoteBean")
   static private MyBeanRemote bean;

   ... 
 }
```

But what I would like to know is: how do I specify the JNDI properties (IP and so) of the first Application Server for the second one to do the look-up?

If there is not a standard way to do this, the servers are JBoss.

Comment: The a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839207/does-ejb-annotation-work-for-remote-call/7842345#7842345

Comment: Thanks, I can hardly believe... :S

Comment: I do believe that some app servers have their proprietary solutions for such things. You should google it as I've just heard (afair) something about Weblogic and their way to inject remote bean.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all i guess there's a bit of confusion in your code.
You shouldn't use a static class annotated with `@Stateless`.

Second why do you call your class `EJBClient` and then annotate it with `@Stateless`?

To answer your question, the lookup method is application server dependent.
In Jboss the EJB name is made by `Context/EJB_Name/remote`. Where the `Context` is your EAR name where you deployed your EJB, the `EJB_Name` is the name of your interface annotated with `@Remote`.

During the lookup process you should specify in the properties where is located the other server.

Hope this help you.